# c# Instagram signup button

Tags: c#, button, click, instagram, innerhtml

< button class="_aj7mu _taytv _ki5uo _o0442">Kaydol < / button >
I want to click the button class name

İnstagram Signup button
< button class="_aj7mu _taytv _ki5uo _o0442">Kaydol < / button >
I want to click the button class name

Instagram Signup button

```
                foreach (HtmlElement item in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
                {
                    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "_aj7mu _taytv _kenyh _qk25s");


                    // burasını ekledm bi test edek olmicak bi dur
                    {

                        item.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're trying to click on the "Kaydol" button on the Instagram web site. It's hard to tell w/o understanding your final goal but you can try using a headless browser for imitating user actions. Have a look at [this project](https://www.nrecosite.com/phantomjs_wrapper_net.aspx) which is a C# wrapper for phantomJS. Also [see here](https://www.andykelk.net/tech/headless-browser-testing-with-phantomjs-selenium-webdriver-c-nunit-and-mono) for an article on couple of headless browser alternatives.